# Why LinkedList as a bucket implementation for HashMap?

Tags: hashmap, bucket

I understand the workings of HashMap -collisions and everything - trying to understand the deeper mechanics and the choice for entry bucket - and not say an Array (making it a 2 dimensional matrix )? Since search through both are O(n) operations ? I assumed one factor that might make the choice for Linked List is the insertions o(1) factor! Is that a correct assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in Java then the linked list is the bucket. And each entry in the table is a linked list containing the array of entry elements. In that each node knows what is in the next to the list till the time you reach to the end when the next reference is null.

Also do check:-

[How does Java's Hashmap work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596549/how-does-javas-hashmap-work-internally/18492835#18492835)

An array has a predetermined size. So if you use an array, then the hash table has a predetermined size for each of the array elements. Every possible bucket is allocated, and your hash table will become big. This will be make sense if you have very huge memory but if not then use link list and walk through the list to find the match.

Comment: I understand that! My question was the reason why a Linked List was chosen as a bucket implementation in the first place! And not ,say, an array?

Comment: Also ff you use an array, the hash table has a predetermined size for each of the array elements. Every possible bucket is allocated, and your hash table can be pretty big. This will be good if you have very huge memory but if not then use link list and walk through the list to find the match

Comment: @user2796381:- Are you looking for the solution in Java??? If yes then do tag the Java tag!! :)

Comment: @user2796381:- The internal implementation of entries that share a common bucket is a plain old linked list. The bucket holds the Map.Entry at the head of the list and each entry has a forward pointer to the next occupant of its bucket.

Comment: No not looking for a solution :) - I just wanted to understand why was the choice was made for Buckets to be am internam implemetnation of a Linked List and not an array based List (i didn't mean a fixed size array - ). Linked lists offer node based implemetnation that certainly help when there are a large number of inserts into the data structure - but when you are adding to the end of list - any growable array based implementation for bucket should suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Its because you do not add at the end of the linkedlist but at the head to make it O(1)
[Answering below question - No not looking for a solution :) - I just wanted to understand why was the choice was made for Buckets to be am internam implemetnation of a Linked List and not an array based List (i didn't mean a fixed size array - ). Linked lists offer node based implemetnation that certainly help when there are a large number of inserts into the data structure - but when you are adding to the end of list - any growable array based implementation for bucket should suffice?]